# Python RecursionError raised Requests 2.26 and Firebase 5.1

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.8, firebase-admin

Since a week I'm facing a weird bug on my python server.
Right now it is running on **Requests** version **2.23.0** without issue.

Because of vulnerability issue I'd like to bump the **Requests** version to the **2.26.0**.

My servers runs ok until I try to run a piece of code like that:

```
import requests
from firebase_admin import auth

bearer_token = requests.headers['X-Bearer-Token'] # Usually there is the word `Bearer`, consider we remove it.
decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(bearer_token, check_revoked=False)
```

This piece of code will raise:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./project/handlers/users.py", line 106, in get_user
    decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(a, check_revoked=False)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/auth.py", line 220, in verify_id_token
    return client.verify_id_token(id_token, check_revoked=check_revoked)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/_auth_client.py", line 127, in verify_id_token
    verified_claims = self._token_verifier.verify_id_token(id_token)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/_token_gen.py", line 293, in verify_id_token
    return self.id_token_verifier.verify(id_token, self.request)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/_token_gen.py", line 396, in verify
    certs_url=self.cert_url)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 124, in verify_token
    certs = _fetch_certs(request, certs_url)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 98, in _fetch_certs
    response = request(certs_url, method="GET")
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/_token_gen.py", line 266, in __call__
    url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers, timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 184, in __call__
    method, url, data=body, headers=headers, timeout=timeout, **kwargs
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 57, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 332, in connect
    cert_reqs=resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs),
  File "./project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 281, in create_urllib3_context
    context.options |= options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 465, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 465, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 465, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  [Previous line repeated 963 more times]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 463, in options
    @options.setter
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Librairies:

- requests = ^2.24.0
- firebase-admin = ^5.0.0

Comment: I also tried with Python 3.8.12 and both Requests versions 2.23.0 and 2.26.0
Same error, it is raised while calling `self.id_token_verifier.verify(id_token, self.request)` from the class TokenVerifier from _token_gen.py file. (Firebase_admin sdk)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the `Eventlet` `Monkey` patch.

> eventlet.monkey_patch()